# Ошибка при обновлении Android Studio 3.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]
Обновляюсь до версии 3.1.2 . Установка доходит до конца.Появляется вот такая ошибка

Comment: Вроде говорит, что эти файлы отсутствуют, проверьте (в папке где установлена студия), попробуйте создать. В крайнем случае скачать с сайта студию целиком и переустановить.

Comment: говорит что эти файлы конфликтуют

Comment: @Cypher Не говорит. Говорит, что их нет.

Comment: а ну да absent же